# Foursquare Trending API Not giving result

Tags: foursquare, trending

I have checked in to few Nearby places from Foursquare app.
Now if I am hitting the foursquare trending api it does not give me the list of checked in venues. Can any one help.
This is the api I have used:
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/trending?ll=23.03,72.58&oauth_token=FMT04M2BJ1.............&v=201....
I have tried this also :
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/trending?near=Ahmedabad&oauth_token=ONPEHQ.....&v=201...
I am Getting such response.

```
{"meta":{"code":200,"requestId":"5925253df594df26def6707a"},"notifications":[{"type":"notificationTray","item":{"unreadCount":0}}],"response":{"venues":[]}}
```

Comment: I Think your usage is correct. This response means there is no trending venue.

Answer (score 1):

You may contact the enterprise team at https://enterprise.foursquare.com

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

There is a minimum number of checkins required to be considered a "trending" venue. If you are the only person checked in that venue won't appear to be trending in the area. Maybe try a test with a lat/lng near a popular venue like SFO airport (37.6213129,-122.3789554) and verify that is gets returned.